# Parsing file in php with no delimiter

Tags: php, parsing

I am working on a project that calls for parsing out some financial files into a database. The files have no delimiters, each record is essentially a huge string and they give me the map of what positions are what field.

Here is one record:

```
GCA0000000188T0544291021BW1079    021BW1079    JOE88TSUSD2015041420150414000000001053060070+000000001053060070+000000001053060070+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000000000000+000000000001053060+000000000001053060+000000000000263265+000000000000000000+021BW107904 042 000000000000000000+00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000PEPPERS AN034   04100003ALTERNATIVE FOCUS   BLUETREND L.P.      HOLDBACK                                                                           NUSD000000000010530600+0000000000+000000010000000000+000000000010530600+USD
```

And the mapping goes something like this:

```
position 000-002 -> Field X

position 003-012 -> Field Y

position 013-023 -> Field Z
```

and so on.

Question here: whats the best way to do this? I am on a php stack. I was thinking about creating methods for each field, passing in the whole string, and returning the values. Is there a package that I can use to help?

Comment: Are you sure that your delimiter isn't a new line?

Comment: If they give you the position and if every lines have the same format, I would write a regexp to split each field. You can then convert to CSV or get the line as an array/object

Comment: see [unpack — Unpack data from binary string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). imo, Fixed length fields in a record is exactly what it is for as it will type convert as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### sscanf

The built-in function [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) works well for fixed-width fields like this - given the proper format it'll parse it out into an array. The format is described in the documentation for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) (which is its counterpart) with only a [few differences](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#refsect1-function.sscanf-parameters).

Here it's pretty simple:

- `%3s` - 3 byte long string
- `%10s` - 10 byte long string
- `%11s` - 11 byte long string

#### Example 1:

```
$fields = sscanf($record, '%3s%10s%11s');
var_dump($fields);
```

#### Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "GCA"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "0000000188"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "T0544291021"
}
```

---

If instead you'd prefer for example to:

- treat the second field as a signed decimal and return it as an integer
- skip the following T
- treat the third field as a signed decimal as well and also return it as an integer

You could use:

- `%3s` - 3 byte long string
- `%10d` - 10 character wide signed decimal
- `T` - literal "T" (not returned)
- `%10d` - 10 character wide signed decimal

#### Example 2:

```
$fields = sscanf($record, '%3s%10dT%10d');
var_dump($fields);
```

#### Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "GCA"
  [1]=>
  int(188)
  [2]=>
  int(544291021)
}
```

---

### unpack

An alternative would be to use [`unpack()`](http://php.net/unpack), whose format information you can find in the documentation for its counterpart [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#refsect1-function.pack-parameters)

- `A3Field X` - Unpack 3 bytes as a string into "Field X"
- `A10Field Y` - Unpack 10 bytes as a string into "Field Y"
- `A11Field Z` - Unpack 11 bytes as a string into "Field Z"

#### Example 3:

```
$fields = unpack('A3Field X/A10Field Y/A11Field Z', $record);
var_dump($fields);
```

#### Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["Field X"]=>
  string(3) "GCA"
  ["Field Y"]=>
  string(10) "0000000188"
  ["Field Z"]=>
  string(11) "T0544291021"
}
```

---

Whether to use `sscanf` or `unpack` depends on the nature of your data and how exactly you need to treat it: `sscanf` does well interpreting characters in the string while `unpack` does well interpreting the bytes that make it up (it's more useful for binary data.)

For example given the string `"1"` with unpack you can get the value of the byte it consists of (i.e. its [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/)):

```
$fields = unpack('c', "1");
var_dump($fields[1]); //int(49)
```

`unpack` is powerful but complex, you can find more information on it at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to just use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) if you have what columns to use.

```
$string = /* the really long string */
$field_x = substr($string, 0, 3);
$field_y = substr($string, 3, 9);
/* etc */
```